# 1 line with 2 different class in Jade?

Tags: pug

I have following code

```
td(class="fieldText") Others Please Specify
```

I want to put different style on `Please Specify`.

How am I able to do it in 1 line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<span>` element to do that:

```css
.fieldText {
  font-size:10px
}

.otherText {
  font-size:50px
}
```

```html
<!--

Jade/pug:

td(class="fieldText") Others 
  span(class="otherText") Please Specify


which outputs as:
-->

<td class="fieldText">Others <span class="otherText">Please Specify</span></td>
```

Comment: @Rendy I see :P I thought that may have been the case but answered anyways as there was no answer.